# Is it possible to replace colladadom dependence with macports?

Tags: ros, robot-model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

robot_model contains a colladadom build, but it doesn't work in OS X (apparently because it's 32-bit instead of 64). However there's also collada-dom in macports. Is it possible to use the macports version instead of the ros-supplied one? Are they different?

If it would be possible, how would that work? (It's not clear to me how rosmake knows to make colladadom in the first place, but it does because it complains about the absence of the stack when I move it out of the robot_model folder. Is it just looking for rosdep.xml files in the sub-dirs?)

FWIW, if I tell collada_urdf that it doesn't need colladdom, then it fails anyway, complaining about missing declarations, which I assume should have been handled by colladadom.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9502/is-it-possible-to-replace-colladadom-dependence-with-macports?/) by [Eponymous](https://answers.ros.org/users/196/eponymous/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2011-03-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on 2015-02-24**:
I have installed the Macports version of collada-dom, and it's the same version required by ROS-Hydro.  But when I try to install ROS-Hydro-Desktop_Full, it complains that it can't find ros-collada-dom.  How would I modify the Portfile for Desktop_Full?  Or how can I make a ros pkg of collada-dom?

**Comment by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on 2015-02-24**:
I've got past collada-dom, but now Macports isn't able to find "python-kitchen".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are several options for adding OSX support.  colladadom is being built from source so it should work for both 32 and 64 bit.  I suggest that you open a ticket with the errors you get when trying to compile.  [Create new robot_model ticket here](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/newticket?component=robot_model&type=defect&&robot_model)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0